# Error while creating a WDP package using AzureToolkit

Tags: azure, paas, packages

I'm trying to create a WDP from an existing Sitecore package but I'm facing the following error **even after installing [DacFX](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55713)**:

```
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedFatalException: The SQL provider cannot run with dacpac option because of a m
issing dependency. Please make sure that DacFx is installed.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2216
72#ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DacHelper.ThrowIfDACCannotBeLoaded()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext addContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ManifestProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext addContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.get_IsValid()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext, Deployme
ntBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions, DeploymentBaseO
ptions baseOptions)
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Packaging.WebDeployPackages.WebDeployPackageBuilder.MSDeploySyncFromManifest(String manifestXmlPath
, String tempPackage)
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Packaging.WebDeployPackages.WebDeployPackageBuilder.Build(SitecoreModuleFolderTree smTree, DirPath
outputDir, String sourceName, String[] disableDacPacOptions, Boolean force)
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.Packaging.ConvertToSCModuleWebDeployPackage.ProcessRecord()
ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage : Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedFatalException: The SQL provider
cannot run with dacpac option because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that DacFx is installed.  Learn more
at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DacHelper.ThrowIfDACCannotBeLoaded()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext addContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.ManifestProvider.GetAttributes(DeploymentAddAttributeContext addContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.EnsureValidAttributes()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.get_IsValid()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObjectPrivate(DeploymentProviderContext providerContext,
DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentObject sourceObject, String serverVersion)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager.CreateObject(DeploymentProviderOptions providerOptions,
DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions)
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Packaging.WebDeployPackages.WebDeployPackageBuilder.MSDeploySyncFromManifest(String
manifestXmlPath, String tempPackage)
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Packaging.WebDeployPackages.WebDeployPackageBuilder.Build(SitecoreModuleFolderTree smTree,
DirPath outputDir, String sourceName, String[] disableDacPacOptions, Boolean force)
   at Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.Packaging.ConvertToSCModuleWebDeployPackage.ProcessRecord()
At line:1 char:1
+ ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path "C:\Sitecore Azure Toolkit\c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Web.D...ProcessRecord():String) [ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPac
   kage], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventId,Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.Packaging.ConvertToSCModuleW
   ebDeployPackage

ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage : The SQL provider cannot run with dacpac option because of a missing dependency.
Please make sure that DacFx is installed.  Learn more at:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DACFX_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.
At line:1 char:1
+ ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage -Path "C:\Sitecore Azure Toolkit\c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertTo-SCModuleWebDeployPackage], DeploymentDetailedFatalException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedFatalException,Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.Packagi
   ng.ConvertToSCModuleWebDeployPackage
```

[image]

I followed the [Sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sat/20/sitecore-azure-toolkit/en/getting-started-with-the-sitecore-azure-toolkit.html) on the subject and made sure **I have all the prerequisites checked**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So yeah, my **DacFX** was installed properly, but...

The only thing that I missed is that **SQL Server itself is a prerequisite as well**.

Since I'm working in a VM which doesn't host any Sitecore instance (it only builds the packages) I didn't realize that quickly.